# Emma instrumentation issue in <instr> ant task

Tags: ant, junit, code-coverage, emma

I have an emma execution target in my ant script which captures the coverage for my project. Following is the ant script snippet from my emma target which worked fine until I added a new project which has the same package names(com.kuleep.project.*) as that of my existing project.

```
    <emma enabled="${emma.enabled}" >
        <instr instrpathref="test.run.classpath"
             destdir="${kulproj.out.instr.dir}" 
             metadatafile="${kulproj.coverage.dir}/metadata.em"
             merge="true">
            <filter includes="com.kuleep.project.*" />
            <filter excludes="com.kuldeep.project.test.*" />
        </instr>
    </emma>
```

After this new project was added the Emma Coverage Report shows the coverage for this new project's package and classes only. This means that the instrumented classes for my old project were overwritten by the instrumented classes of this new project since the package name is same in both projects.

What is the best way to avoid this and have instrumented classes for both projects generated if I do not want to change the package names in either of the projects.

NOTE: Please put a comment if more details are needed to answer this.

Comment: Do the class names from both projects overlap?  As in, does project A have `com.kuleep.project.Foo` and project B also have that class?

Comment: No, class names in 2 projects are all different. They do not overlap.

Comment: It seems like either emma isn't instrumenting both sets of classes, or the uninstrumented classes are appearing first on the classpath when your tests run.  Are the jar / classes from both your project under test and the other one in the `test.run.classpath` path?

Comment: yes, both are in the test.run.classpath.

Comment: Does ${kulproj.out.instr.dir} appear before ${test.run.classpath} in the classpath you're passing to JUnit?

Comment: yes, it appears before ${test.run.classpath} in junit classpath.